Problem with parenting mesh to rig
I have Blender 3.6 on Mac Big Sur.
After many read-throughs, searches, YouTube and multiple attempts, no success at the following:
I open the basic human metarig. I generate a rigify rig. I try to parent the mesh to the rig (to be clear, I choose the mesh first and then the rig) but not allowed to parent with automatic weights.
I know I am missing something so simple but I am driving myself nuts going in circles.
Thank you for your help.
Michael

Where is the mesh? Your screenshot shows a metarig and the generated rig. It looks like you are trying to parent the metarig to the rig. This does not work. They are 2 armatures so you cannot parent them with automatic weights. You need a mesh object.

Once you've generated the rig you can hide the actual armature by unchecking the eye icon against the metarig in the outliner. Now select the mesh and shift-click the rigify controls. Now use Ctrl-P > Parent > Object > With Automatic Weights and you should be good to go. There's a basic tutorial here. It's for Blender 3 but still applies with the latest versions. - As @Blunder says you do need a character mesh though...

Oh my gosh, yes, that makes complete sense. Thank you so much for the speedy response, I so appreciate it.
